# Get Wifi information in Android library project

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am a noob in Android and I want to make an Android library in which I want to check if the device is connected to an Wifi access point. This library will act a helper layer between my backend application and the mobile APP.

I had googled and checked the android developer site but all the examples which I am getting are for APP with an UI. But my library does not have any UI in it.

Can any one point me to any tutorial or document where I can get this information?

Comment: Thanks `@keyboardserfer` for the reply but the answer given in the link provided by you using the "android.app.Activity.getSystemService" method but in my case I have to create only a library files which do not have any activity or UI. This library will be used by a client APP. This library is just an API which the client APP will call with some parameters and I have to verify in the API that Wifi is connected or not. I want to know how I can get the system services info without activity?

Comment: Then you'll need to provide an instance of `Context` to access system methods anyways.

Comment: Thanks. Extending the Activity in library I was able to get the Wifi information.